# Headed down the street

Tags: questions

He pulled up at a busy street corner. Jen got out of the car and headed down the street.

Jen is heading down the sidewalk. Do I have to make that clear or is "headed down the street" enough?

Comment: The reader should take it for granted that she is walking on the sidewalk and not in the middle of the road!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is much that will be assumed.  I'd assume Jen is walking on the sidewalk.  I assume Jen is walking (not hopping or crawling). I assume Jen is a human being.  I assume the "car" is not a railway car, but an automobile....

You can expect your readers to assume common facts like this without needing to write them out.

Comment: Unless stated otherwise!